# Python parent in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, addchild, qtreewidget

I am working on python plugins.I used QTreeWidget  to list items.
[listing in qtreewidget][1]  this link helped me a lot.

My code is:

```
valestimate=QTreeWidgetItem(str(parent_name))
for row in c.fetchall():
         strval=QTreeWidgetItem(unicode(row[0])) 
         valestimate.addChild(strval)
         self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem((valestimate))
```

**parent_name** is name of my parent in **QTreeWidget**.
EX: **'ACO_233'**
But output is :

![enter image description here][2]

If i set columncount as more then one then it is shown as:

![enter image description here][3]

How do i list full string as parent in Qtreewidget??
following this link [single character in qtreewidget][4] ..inserttoplevelitem takes list as parameter..But if i want to make any item as parent ,we cannot add list to qtreewidget type item. How do i do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtreewidgetitem.html#QTreeWidgetItem-2):

```
 QTreeWidgetItem.__init__ (self, QStringList strings, int type = TreeWidgetItem.Type)
```

> Constructs a tree widget item of the specified type. The item must be
>   inserted into a tree widget. The given list of strings will be set as
>   the item text for each column in the item.

`QTreeWidgetItem` expects a *list* of strings to fill in columns. When you do `QTreeWidgetItem(str(parent_name))` it interprets the string `parent_name` as a list of characters (which is what a string is) and puts every character in a column. Instead you should be doing:

```
valestimate = QTreeWidgetItem([parent_name])
```

This will give you a single column item with `parent_name` as the value in that column.

(By the way, `str()` or `unicode()` is not a good way to convert things around. You should use `.encode` to convert `unicode` into `str` or `.decode` for vice versa.)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
        valestimate=QTreeWidgetItem()
        valestimate.setText(0,str(parent_name))
```

Instead of directly converting parent name to qtreewidget type, we can use settext property.